# Probability flux

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a wavefunction $\psi = \pi^{-1\over 4}(1+it)^{-1\over 2} \exp{({-x^2\over 2(1+it)})}$

I want to show that it satisfies 
$\partial_t P +\partial_x j =0$  (*)

I calculated $P=\pi^{-1\over 2}(1+t^2)^{-1\over 2} \exp{({-x^2\over (1+t^2)})}$and  $j=ix\pi^{-1\over 2}(1+t^2)^{-3\over 2} \exp{({-x^2\over (1+t^2)})}$

This gives $\partial_t P = -t\pi^{-1\over 2}(1+t^2)^{-5\over 2} (t^2-2x^2+1)\exp{({-x^2\over (1+t^2)})}$ and $\partial_x j = i\pi^{-1\over 2}(1+t^2)^{-5\over 2} (t^2-2x^2+1)\exp{({-x^2\over (1+t^2)})}$

But how do they satisfy (*)? Perhaps I have got something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the current is

$$j= \frac{i}{2}(\psi\partial_x\psi^*-\psi^*\partial_x\psi) \; ,$$

implying that for your choice of wave function

$$j=t x \pi^{-1/2}(1+t^2)^{-3/2}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{1+t^2}\right) \; .$$

Try computing $\partial_x j$ again, it should work out fine now.

**EDIT:**

So,

$$\partial_x\psi= \pi^{-1/4}(1-it)^{-1/2}\left(-\frac{x}{1-it}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2(1-it)}\right) \; ,$$

and

$$\partial_x\psi^*= \pi^{-1/4}(1+it)^{-1/2}\left(-\frac{x}{1+it}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2(1+it)}\right) \; .$$

Multiplying by $\psi^*$ and $\psi$ respectively, one gets

$$\psi^*\partial_x\psi= \pi^{-1/2}(1+t^2)^{-1/2}\left(-\frac{x}{1+it}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{(1+t^2)}\right) \; ,$$

and

$$\psi\partial_x\psi^*= \pi^{-1/2}(1+t^2)^{-1/2}\left(-\frac{x}{1-it}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{(1+t^2)}\right) \; .$$

Finally, subtract both and multiply by $i/2$ to get the current $j$.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get from the 2nd expression for j you have given (sorry for being daft) where did the t come from?

Comment: OK, I'll expand my answer. The $t$ comes from the difference of the two conjugate terms. Because of the derivative with respect to $x$, you carry a factor containing $t$.

Comment: Ahhhh! Thanks! I know what went wrong now, I have been stupidly adding the complex conjugates, despite knowing that I should be subtracting them. Thanks again!